# Detect object in video and augment another video on top of it

Tags: computer-vision, image-recognition, object-detection, object-recognition, algorithm-request

I'm trying to detect an object in a video (with slight camera movement), and then augment another video on top of it. What is the simplest approach to do that?

For instance, let's assume I have this simple video of a couch [**HERE**](https://streamable.com/dzh0at). Now I want to augment the **right cusion** with a human or a dog. The dog or human are video itself (let's assume transparency is not an issue).

What's the simplest approach to do that?

[image]